# Caching not work after postback asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have An asp.net Page And Set OutPutCashing Location="**Client**" when i load page and reload , page load not work but when click a buttom and postback page , caching not working 
I Need page load not run

Comment: @alisghar, how your data is being loaded, i mean you will be using web service ? so in service you using GET or POST?

Comment: @Webruster i not use web service , i use Post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is
>   either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location
>   or Content-Location headers (if present). These methods are:
>
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - POST

So, to make cache work, you need to convert your POST to GET.